# Enlarge UITabBarViewController buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbaritem

I am using a `UITabBarViewController` in my iOS project and my tab button texts are really `thin/small`.

How do I enlarge the text on the buttons? How do I change the `TabBar` color to be more distinguishable?

Comment: I just noticed the buttons ARE large, it's just that the font of the text is small and can barely be noticed. Also - how do I change the color of the Tab Bar? Thanks !

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include your comment about the text and changing the color. Adding an image o the tabbar might help people understand.